# How to know which AWS CodeBuild quota to increase?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-service-quotas

I have configured `AWS CodePipeline` using `AWS CDK`.

This pipeline deploys multiple stacks along with approximately ~60 cloud functions. During deployment, I noticed that assets (lambdas) were failing due to exceeding the default limit of parallel builds in `AWS CodeBuild`.

After conducting some research, I discovered that this limit can be increased by contacting `AWS Support`. I also found that AWS provides a `Service Quota` service that can be used to request an increase. To make this request, I need answers to two questions

1. How many parallel builds do I need according to my needs?
2. What quota I need to increase from the list (it has too many environments which do not match 1 to 1 with my environment)?

This is my pipeline example
[image]

This is environment used by assets
[image]

This is a list of quotas that can be increased
[image]

P.S. I'm also wondering if increasing the limit would result in an increase in deployment costs. I can deploy those functions sequentially, but it takes some time, or I can increase the quota to make it faster (which might be more expensive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't increase the costs per say as you run more CodeBuilds faster. You need to ask for related CodeBuild concurrency (small, medium or large). E.g. ask 25 for Concurrently running builds for Linux/Small environment

Comment: Regarding the environments... Before asking this question, I didn't know that the default AWS CDK uses a 4GB EC2 instance, which is considered "Small." So I have somewhat resolved this misunderstanding, but yeah, I didn't know that concurrent builds don't increase the cost... Thanks!